# Number of roots of unity in a finite cyclic group G, source to cite

Tags: group-theory, reference-request, gcd-and-lcm, cyclic-groups, roots-of-unity

Can anybody point me to an official book or paper that has a complete proof to the statement

In a finite cyclic group $G$ then number of solutions to $x^n = 1$ is $\gcd(n,|G|)$

I have pieced together a proof using other stack exchange post but want to use an official reference to cite in my bachelor thesis.

Thanks a lot

Comment: Let $d=\gcd(n, |G|)$. and let $g\in G$ be a generator.  Then $g^i$  satisfies $g^{in}=e$ iff $|G|\,|\,in$ whence $i\in \{\frac {0\times |G|}d, \frac {1\times |G|}d, \cdots , \frac {(d-1)\times |G|}d\}$.  Hence there are exactly  $d$ instances.

Comment: As written, the statement is false unless you specify $G$ is finite. For finite groups, the solutions form a subgroup of order dividing both $n$ and $|G|$, hence of order dividing $\gcd(n,|G|)$, and every element of the subgroup of order $\gcd(n,|G|)$ satisfies the equation.,

Comment: Yes of course, added the finite condition. Thank you both very much, could you point me to a book or paper that I could use to cite this result?

Comment: I would recommend that you include a complete and accurate proof in your thesis, saying something like this is a well-known result but you failed to locate a convenient reference. That is standard practice.